# How can I purchase new assets for my Roth IRA while residing in Canada?

Tags: canada, roth-ira, vanguard

I'm a US citizen and currently reside and study in Canada.

My Roth IRA is currently at Vanguard (in the US).  While I reside in Canada, they do not allow me to purchase new assets with the funds that I have in my Roth IRA.

Does anyone know or understand the reason for this?

More importantly, is there another similar service I could use that would allow me to purchase new assets while I continue to reside in Canada?

Comment: Another idea: would it be possible to temporarily change my residency back to US?  I don't plan to actively manage my portfolio, I just want to purchase higher return assets (once).

Comment: Have you contacted Vanguard? This sounds unusual.

Comment: Yes, twice.  That is how I know their policy.

Comment: What did they give for the reasons?

Comment: From what I understood, basically there are some legal issues which are not completely trivial to deal with, and so they have this simple rule as a way of avoiding that (which makes sense, since they are all about low overhead)

Comment: Since the "TD" in TD Ameritrade stands for Toronto Dominion, I'd hope they have figured out the U.S.-Can issue.

Comment: Thanks, I just talked to TD and it sounds like that is going to work out fine.

Comment: It's likely you cannot contribute directly to your Roth IRA unless you have US sourced income. If you use the foreign earned income exclusion, you can only contribute directly to a Roth IRA if you earn more than the income exclusion but less than the contribution cut off.

Comment: I don't want to contribute, just reinvest the funds I have.